# SQL Query Order by intercalated

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

First of all, thanks for your time!

I have a recurrence pattern mapped in my database (e.g. google calendar events), I'm trying to perform a query that sorts results by distance and startDate, but I can't make it work. Here is my query:

```
select
    cast(e.id as varchar),
    e.starts_at as startsAt ,
    e.ends_at as endsAt,
    e.name,
    e.description,
    e.picture,
    e.is_full_day as isFullDay,
    e.is_private as isPrivate,
    e.show_guest_list as showGuestList,
    e.friend_can_invite_friends as friendsCanInviteFriends,
    e.timezone_name as timezoneName,
    (
    select
        id
    from
        event_recurrences er
    where
        er.event_id = e.id
    limit 1) is not null as isRecurring,
    case
        when p.id is not null
        and l.sublocality is not null then CONCAT(p."name", ', ', l.sublocality)
        when p.id is not null
        and l.sublocality is null then p."name"
        when p.id is null
        and l.sublocality is not null then CONCAT(l.sublocality, ' - ' , c."name")
        else l.formatted_address
    end as addressOrPlaceName,
    cast(p.id as varchar) as placeId,
    cast(e.thumbs as varchar),
    case
        when null is not null
        and null is not null then earth_distance( ll_to_earth(cast(cast(null as text) as double precision),
        cast(cast(null as text)as double precision)),
        ll_to_earth(l.lat,
        l.lng)) / 1000
    end as distance
from
    recurring_events_for('2022-07-05T20:44:55.016+0000',
    '2023-07-05T20:44:55.016+0000',
    'UTC-3',
    15,
    false) e
inner join locations l on
    e.location_id = l.id
inner join cities c on
    l.city_id = c.id
left join places p on
    p.location_id = l.id
where
    e.is_private = false
    and (null is null
        or c.id = cast(cast(null as text) as UUID))
order by
    distance,
    startsAt;
```

I get the following results:

```
id                                  |startsat               |distance          |endsat                 |name         |description |picture                                 |isfullday|isprivate|showguestlist|friendscaninvitefriends|timezonename|isrecurring|addressorplacename   |placeid|thumbs                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |
------------------------------------+-----------------------+------------------+-----------------------+-------------+------------+----------------------------------------+---------+---------+-------------+-----------------------+------------+-----------+---------------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
c6a2c94c-04ad-4b11-99ca-235a9be6ece7|2022-07-05 20:30:00.000| 7814.717238024624|2022-07-05 22:30:00.000|evento google|manaus      |                                        |false    |false    |false        |false                  |UTC-3       |false      |Chapada - Manaus     |       |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
c6a2c94c-04ad-4b11-99ca-235a9be6ece7|2022-07-06 20:30:00.000| 7814.717238024624|2022-07-06 22:30:00.000|evento google|manaus      |                                        |false    |false    |false        |false                  |UTC-3       |false      |Chapada - Manaus     |       |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
c6a2c94c-04ad-4b11-99ca-235a9be6ece7|2022-07-07 20:30:00.000| 7814.717238024624|2022-07-07 22:30:00.000|evento google|manaus      |                                        |false    |false    |false        |false                  |UTC-3       |false      |Chapada - Manaus     |       |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
c6a2c94c-04ad-4b11-99ca-235a9be6ece7|2022-07-08 20:30:00.000| 7814.717238024624|2022-07-08 22:30:00.000|evento google|manaus      |                                        |false    |false    |false        |false                  |UTC-3       |false      |Chapada - Manaus     |       |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
c6a2c94c-04ad-4b11-99ca-235a9be6ece7|2022-07-09 20:30:00.000| 7814.717238024624|2022-07-09 22:30:00.000|evento google|manaus      |                                        |false    |false    |false        |false                  |UTC-3       |false      |Chapada - Manaus     |       |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
c6a2c94c-04ad-4b11-99ca-235a9be6ece7|2022-07-10 20:30:00.000| 7814.717238024624|2022-07-10 22:30:00.000|evento google|manaus      |                                        |false    |false    |false        |false                  |UTC-3       |false      |Chapada - Manaus     |       |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
c6a2c94c-04ad-4b11-99ca-235a9be6ece7|2022-07-11 20:30:00.000| 7814.717238024624|2022-07-11 22:30:00.000|evento google|manaus      |                                        |false    |false    |false        |false                  |UTC-3       |false      |Chapada - Manaus     |       |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
c6a2c94c-04ad-4b11-99ca-235a9be6ece7|2022-07-12 20:30:00.000| 7814.717238024624|2022-07-12 22:30:00.000|evento google|manaus      |                                        |false    |false    |false        |false                  |UTC-3       |false      |Chapada - Manaus     |       |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
c6a2c94c-04ad-4b11-99ca-235a9be6ece7|2022-07-13 20:30:00.000| 7814.717238024624|2022-07-13 22:30:00.000|evento google|manaus      |                                        |false    |false    |false        |false                  |UTC-3       |false      |Chapada - Manaus     |       |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
c6a2c94c-04ad-4b11-99ca-235a9be6ece7|2022-07-14 20:30:00.000| 7814.717238024624|2022-07-14 22:30:00.000|evento google|manaus      |                                        |false    |false    |false        |false                  |UTC-3       |false      |Chapada - Manaus     |       |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
c6a2c94c-04ad-4b11-99ca-235a9be6ece7|2022-07-15 20:30:00.000| 7814.717238024624|2022-07-15 22:30:00.000|evento google|manaus      |                                        |false    |false    |false        |false                  |UTC-3       |false      |Chapada - Manaus     |       |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
c6a2c94c-04ad-4b11-99ca-235a9be6ece7|2022-07-16 20:30:00.000| 7814.717238024624|2022-07-16 22:30:00.000|evento google|manaus      |                                        |false    |false    |false        |false                  |UTC-3       |false      |Chapada - Manaus     |       |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
c6a2c94c-04ad-4b11-99ca-235a9be6ece7|2022-07-17 20:30:00.000| 7814.717238024624|2022-07-17 22:30:00.000|evento google|manaus      |                                        |false    |false    |false        |false                  |UTC-3       |false      |Chapada - Manaus     |       |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
c6a2c94c-04ad-4b11-99ca-235a9be6ece7|2022-07-18 20:30:00.000| 7814.717238024624|2022-07-18 22:30:00.000|evento google|manaus      |                                        |false    |false    |false        |false                  |UTC-3       |false      |Chapada - Manaus     |       |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
c6a2c94c-04ad-4b11-99ca-235a9be6ece7|2022-07-19 20:30:00.000| 7814.717238024624|2022-07-19 22:30:00.000|evento google|manaus      |                                        |false    |false    |false        |false                  |UTC-3       |false      |Chapada - Manaus     |       |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
9a9fd609-d3c2-45cf-aaff-1917a02aba11|2022-07-05 20:00:00.000| 10397.27140682366|2022-07-05 22:00:00.000|tesgte       |asdsadsadsad|                                        |false    |false    |false        |false                  |UTC-3       |false      |Pinheiros - São Paulo|       |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
2aa119fc-5528-4b60-b482-7a20b3b38e27|2022-07-05 21:00:00.000| 10397.27140682366|2022-07-05 21:30:00.000|teate        |sadsad      |8bc62c73-7438-46c6-90c8-b376168f516e.png|false    |false    |false        |false                  |UTC-3       |false      |Pinheiros - São Paulo|       |[{"size": "200x200", "success": true, "outputFilePath": "events/2aa119fc-5528-4b60-b482-7a20b3b38e27/thumb/8bc62c73-7438-46c6-90c8-b376168f516e_200x200.webp"}, {"size": "400x400", "success": true, "outputFilePath": "events/2aa119fc-5528-4b60-b482-7a20b3b3|
2aa119fc-5528-4b60-b482-7a20b3b38e27|2022-07-06 21:00:00.000| 10397.27140682366|2022-07-06 21:30:00.000|teate        |sadsad      |8bc62c73-7438-46c6-90c8-b376168f516e.png|false    |false    |false        |false                  |UTC-3       |false      |Pinheiros - São Paulo|       |[{"size": "200x200", "success": true, "outputFilePath": "events/2aa119fc-5528-4b60-b482-7a20b3b38e27/thumb/8bc62c73-7438-46c6-90c8-b376168f516e_200x200.webp"}, {"size": "400x400", "success": true, "outputFilePath": "events/2aa119fc-5528-4b60-b482-7a20b3b3|
2aa119fc-5528-4b60-b482-7a20b3b38e27|2022-07-07 21:00:00.000| 10397.27140682366|2022-07-07 21:30:00.000|teate        |sadsad      |8bc62c73-7438-46c6-90c8-b376168f516e.png|false    |false    |false        |false                  |UTC-3       |false      |Pinheiros - São Paulo|       |[{"size": "200x200", "success": true, "outputFilePath": "events/2aa119fc-5528-4b60-b482-7a20b3b38e27/thumb/8bc62c73-7438-46c6-90c8-b376168f516e_200x200.webp"}, {"size": "400x400", "success": true, "outputFilePath": "events/2aa119fc-5528-4b60-b482-7a20b3b3|
2aa119fc-5528-4b60-b482-7a20b3b38e27|2022-07-08 21:00:00.000| 10397.27140682366|2022-07-08 21:30:00.000|teate        |sadsad      |8bc62c73-7438-46c6-90c8-b376168f516e.png|false    |false    |false        |false                  |UTC-3       |false      |Pinheiros - São Paulo|       |[{"size": "200x200", "success": true, "outputFilePath": "events/2aa119fc-5528-4b60-b482-7a20b3b38e27/thumb/8bc62c73-7438-46c6-90c8-b376168f516e_200x200.webp"}, {"size": "400x400", "success": true, "outputFilePath": "events/2aa119fc-5528-4b60-b482-7a20b3b3|
2aa119fc-5528-4b60-b482-7a20b3b38e27|2022-07-09 21:00:00.000| 10397.27140682366|2022-07-09 21:30:00.000|teate        |sadsad      |8bc62c73-7438-46c6-90c8-b376168f516e.png|false    |false    |false        |false                  |UTC-3       |false      |Pinheiros - São Paulo|       |[{"size": "200x200", "success": true, "outputFilePath": "events/2aa119fc-5528-4b60-b482-7a20b3b38e27/thumb/8bc62c73-7438-46c6-90c8-b376168f516e_200x200.webp"}, {"size": "400x400", "success": true, "outputFilePath": "events/2aa119fc-5528-4b60-b482-7a20b3b3|
2aa119fc-5528-4b60-b482-7a20b3b38e27|2022-07-10 21:00:00.000| 10397.27140682366|2022-07-10 21:30:00.000|teate        |sadsad      |8bc62c73-7438-46c6-90c8-b376168f516e.png|false    |false    |false        |false                  |UTC-3       |false      |Pinheiros - São Paulo|       |[{"size": "200x200", "success": true, "outputFilePath": "events/2aa119fc-5528-4b60-b482-7a20b3b38e27/thumb/8bc62c73-7438-46c6-90c8-b376168f516e_200x200.webp"}, {"size": "400x400", "success": true, "outputFilePath": "events/2aa119fc-5528-4b60-b482-7a20b3b3|
2aa119fc-5528-4b60-b482-7a20b3b38e27|2022-07-11 21:00:00.000| 10397.27140682366|2022-07-11 21:30:00.000|teate        |sadsad      |8bc62c73-7438-46c6-90c8-b376168f516e.png|false    |false    |false        |false                  |UTC-3       |false      |Pinheiros - São Paulo|       |[{"size": "200x200", "success": true, "outputFilePath": "events/2aa119fc-5528-4b60-b482-7a20b3b38e27/thumb/8bc62c73-7438-46c6-90c8-b376168f516e_200x200.webp"}, {"size": "400x400", "success": true, "outputFilePath": "events/2aa119fc-5528-4b60-b482-7a20b3b3|
2aa119fc-5528-4b60-b482-7a20b3b38e27|2022-07-12 21:00:00.000| 10397.27140682366|2022-07-12 21:30:00.000|teate        |sadsad      |8bc62c73-7438-46c6-90c8-b376168f516e.png|false    |false    |false        |false                  |UTC-3       |false      |Pinheiros - São Paulo|       |[{"size": "200x200", "success": true, "outputFilePath": "events/2aa119fc-5528-4b60-b482-7a20b3b38e27/thumb/8bc62c73-7438-46c6-90c8-b376168f516e_200x200.webp"}, {"size": "400x400", "success": true, "outputFilePath": "events/2aa119fc-5528-4b60-b482-7a20b3b3|
2aa119fc-5528-4b60-b482-7a20b3b38e27|2022-07-13 21:00:00.000| 10397.27140682366|2022-07-13 21:30:00.000|teate        |sadsad      |8bc62c73-7438-46c6-90c8-b376168f516e.png|false    |false    |false        |false                  |UTC-3       |false      |Pinheiros - São Paulo|       |[{"size": "200x200", "success": true, "outputFilePath": "events/2aa119fc-5528-4b60-b482-7a20b3b38e27/thumb/8bc62c73-7438-46c6-90c8-b376168f516e_200x200.webp"}, {"size": "400x400", "success": true, "outputFilePath": "events/2aa119fc-5528-4b60-b482-7a20b3b3|
2aa119fc-5528-4b60-b482-7a20b3b38e27|2022-07-14 21:00:00.000| 10397.27140682366|2022-07-14 21:30:00.000|teate        |sadsad      |8bc62c73-7438-46c6-90c8-b376168f516e.png|false    |false    |false        |false                  |UTC-3       |false      |Pinheiros - São Paulo|       |[{"size": "200x200", "success": true, "outputFilePath": "events/2aa119fc-5528-4b60-b482-7a20b3b38e27/thumb/8bc62c73-7438-46c6-90c8-b376168f516e_200x200.webp"}, {"size": "400x400", "success": true, "outputFilePath": "events/2aa119fc-5528-4b60-b482-7a20b3b3|
2aa119fc-5528-4b60-b482-7a20b3b38e27|2022-07-15 21:00:00.000| 10397.27140682366|2022-07-15 21:30:00.000|teate        |sadsad      |8bc62c73-7438-46c6-90c8-b376168f516e.png|false    |false    |false        |false                  |UTC-3       |false      |Pinheiros - São Paulo|       |[{"size": "200x200", "success": true, "outputFilePath": "events/2aa119fc-5528-4b60-b482-7a20b3b38e27/thumb/8bc62c73-7438-46c6-90c8-b376168f516e_200x200.webp"}, {"size": "400x400", "success": true, "outputFilePath": "events/2aa119fc-5528-4b60-b482-7a20b3b3|
2aa119fc-5528-4b60-b482-7a20b3b38e27|2022-07-16 21:00:00.000| 10397.27140682366|2022-07-16 21:30:00.000|teate        |sadsad      |8bc62c73-7438-46c6-90c8-b376168f516e.png|false    |false    |false        |false                  |UTC-3       |false      |Pinheiros - São Paulo|       |[{"size": "200x200", "success": true, "outputFilePath": "events/2aa119fc-5528-4b60-b482-7a20b3b38e27/thumb/8bc62c73-7438-46c6-90c8-b376168f516e_200x200.webp"}, {"size": "400x400", "success": true, "outputFilePath": "events/2aa119fc-5528-4b60-b482-7a20b3b3|
2aa119fc-5528-4b60-b482-7a20b3b38e27|2022-07-17 21:00:00.000| 10397.27140682366|2022-07-17 21:30:00.000|teate        |sadsad      |8bc62c73-7438-46c6-90c8-b376168f516e.png|false    |false    |false        |false                  |UTC-3       |false      |Pinheiros - São Paulo|       |[{"size": "200x200", "success": true, "outputFilePath": "events/2aa119fc-5528-4b60-b482-7a20b3b38e27/thumb/8bc62c73-7438-46c6-90c8-b376168f516e_200x200.webp"}, {"size": "400x400", "success": true, "outputFilePath": "events/2aa119fc-5528-4b60-b482-7a20b3b3|
2aa119fc-5528-4b60-b482-7a20b3b38e27|2022-07-18 21:00:00.000| 10397.27140682366|2022-07-18 21:30:00.000|teate        |sadsad      |8bc62c73-7438-46c6-90c8-b376168f516e.png|false    |false    |false        |false                  |UTC-3       |false      |Pinheiros - São Paulo|       |[{"size": "200x200", "success": true, "outputFilePath": "events/2aa119fc-5528-4b60-b482-7a20b3b38e27/thumb/8bc62c73-7438-46c6-90c8-b376168f516e_200x200.webp"}, {"size": "400x400", "success": true, "outputFilePath": "events/2aa119fc-5528-4b60-b482-7a20b3b3|
2aa119fc-5528-4b60-b482-7a20b3b38e27|2022-07-19 21:00:00.000| 10397.27140682366|2022-07-19 21:30:00.000|teate        |sadsad      |8bc62c73-7438-46c6-90c8-b376168f516e.png|false    |false    |false        |false                  |UTC-3       |false      |Pinheiros - São Paulo|       |[{"size": "200x200", "success": true, "outputFilePath": "events/2aa119fc-5528-4b60-b482-7a20b3b38e27/thumb/8bc62c73-7438-46c6-90c8-b376168f516e_200x200.webp"}, {"size": "400x400", "success": true, "outputFilePath": "events/2aa119fc-5528-4b60-b482-7a20b3b3|
d4d5927b-2951-423b-9c21-32beb1aa05ff|2022-07-05 20:00:00.000|10401.432664731024|2022-07-05 22:00:00.000|recorrente   |dasdsad     |                                        |false    |false    |false        |false                  |UTC-3       |false      |Centro - Guarulhos   |       |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
d4d5927b-2951-423b-9c21-32beb1aa05ff|2022-07-06 20:00:00.000|10401.432664731024|2022-07-06 22:00:00.000|recorrente   |dasdsad     |                                        |false    |false    |false        |false                  |UTC-3       |false      |Centro - Guarulhos   |       |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
d4d5927b-2951-423b-9c21-32beb1aa05ff|2022-07-07 20:00:00.000|10401.432664731024|2022-07-07 22:00:00.000|recorrente   |dasdsad     |                                        |false    |false    |false        |false                  |UTC-3       |false      |Centro - Guarulhos   |       |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
d4d5927b-2951-423b-9c21-32beb1aa05ff|2022-07-08 20:00:00.000|10401.432664731024|2022-07-08 22:00:00.000|recorrente   |dasdsad     |                                        |false    |false    |false        |false                  |UTC-3       |false      |Centro - Guarulhos   |       |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
d4d5927b-2951-423b-9c21-32beb1aa05ff|2022-07-09 20:00:00.000|10401.432664731024|2022-07-09 22:00:00.000|recorrente   |dasdsad     |                                        |false    |false    |false        |false                  |UTC-3       |false      |Centro - Guarulhos   |       |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
d4d5927b-2951-423b-9c21-32beb1aa05ff|2022-07-10 20:00:00.000|10401.432664731024|2022-07-10 22:00:00.000|recorrente   |dasdsad     |                                        |false    |false    |false        |false                  |UTC-3       |false      |Centro - Guarulhos   |       |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
d4d5927b-2951-423b-9c21-32beb1aa05ff|2022-07-11 20:00:00.000|10401.432664731024|2022-07-11 22:00:00.000|recorrente   |dasdsad     |                                        |false    |false    |false        |false                  |UTC-3       |false      |Centro - Guarulhos   |       |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
d4d5927b-2951-423b-9c21-32beb1aa05ff|2022-07-12 20:00:00.000|10401.432664731024|2022-07-12 22:00:00.000|recorrente   |dasdsad     |                                        |false    |false    |false        |false                  |UTC-3       |false      |Centro - Guarulhos   |       |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
d4d5927b-2951-423b-9c21-32beb1aa05ff|2022-07-13 20:00:00.000|10401.432664731024|2022-07-13 22:00:00.000|recorrente   |dasdsad     |                                        |false    |false    |false        |false                  |UTC-3       |false      |Centro - Guarulhos   |       |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
d4d5927b-2951-423b-9c21-32beb1aa05ff|2022-07-14 20:00:00.000|10401.432664731024|2022-07-14 22:00:00.000|recorrente   |dasdsad     |                                        |false    |false    |false        |false                  |UTC-3       |false      |Centro - Guarulhos   |       |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
d4d5927b-2951-423b-9c21-32beb1aa05ff|2022-07-15 20:00:00.000|10401.432664731024|2022-07-15 22:00:00.000|recorrente   |dasdsad     |                                        |false    |false    |false        |false                  |UTC-3       |false      |Centro - Guarulhos   |       |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
d4d5927b-2951-423b-9c21-32beb1aa05ff|2022-07-19 20:00:00.000|10401.432664731024|2022-07-19 22:00:00.000|recorrente   |dasdsad     |                                        |false    |false    |false        |false                  |UTC-3       |false      |Centro - Guarulhos   |       |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
```

As you can see, it repeats closest events, sorting by startsat, then changes the event, do the same. What I need is something like this:

```
id                                  |startsat               |distance          |endsat                 |name         |description |picture                                 |isfullday|isprivate|showguestlist|friendscaninvitefriends|timezonename|isrecurring|addressorplacename   |placeid|thumbs                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |
------------------------------------+-----------------------+------------------+-----------------------+-------------+------------+----------------------------------------+---------+---------+-------------+-----------------------+------------+-----------+---------------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
c6a2c94c-04ad-4b11-99ca-235a9be6ece7|2022-07-05 20:30:00.000| 7814.717238024624|2022-07-05 22:30:00.000|evento google|manaus      |                                        |false    |false    |false        |false                  |UTC-3       |false      |Chapada - Manaus     |       |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
9a9fd609-d3c2-45cf-aaff-1917a02aba11|2022-07-05 20:00:00.000| 10397.27140682366|2022-07-05 22:00:00.000|tesgte       |asdsadsadsad|                                        |false    |false    |false        |false                  |UTC-3       |false      |Pinheiros - São Paulo|       |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
2aa119fc-5528-4b60-b482-7a20b3b38e27|2022-07-05 21:00:00.000| 10397.27140682366|2022-07-05 21:30:00.000|teate        |sadsad      |8bc62c73-7438-46c6-90c8-b376168f516e.png|false    |false    |false        |false                  |UTC-3       |false      |Pinheiros - São Paulo|       |[{"size": "200x200", "success": true, "outputFilePath": "events/2aa119fc-5528-4b60-b482-7a20b3b38e27/thumb/8bc62c73-7438-46c6-90c8-b376168f516e_200x200.webp"}, {"size": "400x400", "success": true, "outputFilePath": "events/2aa119fc-5528-4b60-b482-7a20b3b3|
```

As you can see, it is sorted by closest distance on the same day! Then it repeats on the next day and so on.

Hope I was clear, if not, I can improve my question!

Thanks again

Comment: For rows with `startsat, distance` as the following: `2022-07-20 20:30:00.000| 7814.717238024624` and `2022-07-05 20:00:00.000| 10397.27140682366` which one should appear first? It's clear that for the same day the priority of sorting is according to distance, but what about events with different dates, is it also for distance not the date?

Comment: I think a simple `DISTINCT ON (e.id)` will probably give you what you want.

Comment: `order by startsat::date, distance, startsat`

Comment: @Ahmed thanks for answering! So, the query should bring first the closest events on Day 1. If the next event happens on D+2, it should bring the closest (in distance) and the earlier (startsAt)

Comment: @MikeOrganek it worked, thanks! If you don't mind, add it as an answer, so I can mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to "group" results by day while seeing all rows, add the date as part of the `order by`.

```
order by
    startsAt::date,
    distance,
    startsAt;
```